# z3py: how to cast bitvec in python math functions?

Tags: z3py

I'd like to calculate the actually used length of a bitvec. For example, we have a bitvec like 00101100, and the actually used length is 6 in terms of the position of the most right 1. Anyway, I have a code in z3py as follows:

```
from z3 import *
import math
def length(t):
return int(math.ceil(math.log(t,2)))
```

well, if I use an integer as input, that is no problem at all because that is a pure python code in fact. If I use

```
x = BitVecVal(31,8) 
print length(x)
```

Then, I got a problem as instance has no attribute **float** . I've tried z3_mk_bv2int, or ToInt(). But none of them worked.

Please help me to sort it out, or that is not allowed in z3py.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is "official" way, but you can get string representation and then parse it to integer:

```
x = BitVecVal(42, 8)
value = int(str(x))
print value, type(value)

42 <type 'int'>
```